# Write a List in a file with a return to the line

Tags: android, listview, file-io

I'm facing a problem: I want to store a list then read/display it from a file !
In fact, the problem is when writing the list, it just writes it without any end of line or any conditions, code:

```
try {
            fOut = context.openFileOutput(nom, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++ )
            {
                osw.write(list.get(i));
            }
            osw.flush();
            osw.close();
            fOut.close();
```

Data stored:

```
data = date + " : " + ans + " L/100km\n" + litre + " litres "+ km + " km\n";

ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, list);
        L.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Can i modify this line `osw.write(list.get(i));`or add another line(s) to make an end of line after every data!
Thank you.

Comment: Please add the code that creates the list you are using.

Comment: @MByD: 1st post edited !

Comment: Does my edited answer answers your Q, or did I get you wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osw.write(list.get(i) + "\n");` should do the job.

To add line break every X lines, you can modify your for loop this way:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++ )
     {
         osw.write(list.get(i));
         if ((i+1) % X == 0)  // change X to desired number
            {
               osw.write("\n");
            }
     }
```

Comment: Unbelievable simple and unblievable useful ! Thank you for helping me, excellent answer ;) !

Comment: But i just want how it works ! how it know that it has to return to the line after the specific word ! Strange :\

Comment: @Dante Jiang: I know that "\n" returns to the line ! But, my datas are saved in one line, and i want it to retun just after a specific word, when i maked this osw.write(list.get(i) + "\n"); it exactly returns to the line after the desired word ! thay's why i said it's strange ;) !

Comment: @androiennn, and just a bit more: http://ehis.ebscohost.com.mms02.cerritos.edu/jwilson/java_language_resources/Java_Escape_Sequences.htm

Comment: Thank you for this links, but i told you what i want to know :).

Comment: We need to see some more of your code. probably you splat the line to list of words in the part before the code snippet you gave :)

Comment: Yes, exactly, in fact, i'm deleting an item from a listview, deleting all file contents, then adding the new items(with item seleceted deleted)! Before deleting the file contents, the datas are well displayed just like i want! but the thing that i find is bizarre is (for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i ++ )
            {
                osw.write(list.get(i));
            }) it can returns to the end of line after 2words(of the data stored) or after 3, 4 ... words. you know what i mean ?